# Are there problems at the interface of group theory and calculus?

Tags: calculus, group-theory, soft-question

I wonder whether there are mathematical problems that require the joint use of *group theory* and *calculus*? Can someone please give me an example if there are any?

Comment: Harmonic analysis as a branch of mathematics involves a lot of overlap.

Comment: can you please tell me  a specific problem?

Comment: Unfortunately no. It was not my field of study. I only know about the closeness because a fellow grad student was in the field and remarked how much group theory he was using. Try the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_analysis) page for some general descriptions of problem types and techniques.

Answer (score 2):

[Lie theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_theory) is basically a marriage of analytic geometry to group theory. (That's not the best description, but it's at least a partial one.)

An exponential map is used to communicate between a Lie group and its Lie algebra, which is sometimes defined as a space of differentials. You can do all sorts of calculus on $\Bbb R^n$ and real manifolds this way.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an elementary result about periodic functions.

- The set of periods of a function $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is an additive subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$.
- An additive subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$ is either dense or discrete.
- The set of periods of a non-constant *continuous* function $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a discrete additive subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

[Dirichlet's Theorem](https://www.princeton.edu/~achaney/tmve/wiki100k/docs/Dirichlet_s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions.html) about arithmetic progressions involves both group theory and analysis.

Answer (score 0):

An additive subgroup $G$ of $\Bbb R$ is either dense or discrete, and in fact this is sorted out by finding $\vartheta=\inf\{g\in G:g>0\}$. If $\vartheta =0$, the group is dense, if $\vartheta>0$ the group is discrete, and equals $\vartheta\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Lot of thanks to all of you for the interesting examples